# How can I make a this selection of groups and members simpler and more efficient?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

## Background

I've got a **group** table, **users** table, and a **group_members** table.

```
groups { group_ varchar(50) not null, etc... }
users  { user_id varchar(50) not null, etc... }
group_members { group_ varchar(50 not null, member varchar(50) not null }
```

My requirements state that a group can have other groups as members.  The user needs to be considered a member of all groups that any group they are a member of.
For Example, consider the following data in these tables:

```
group_members              | groups         | users    |
========================== | ============== | ======== |
group_          member     | group_         | user_id  |
-------------------------- | -------------- | -------- |
'SYSTEM_ADMIN'  'OE_ADMIN' | 'SYSTEM_ADMIN' | 'USER    |
'SYSTEM_ADMIN'  'AR_ADMIN' | 'OE_ADMIN'     |          |
'SYSTEM_ADMIN'  'USER'     | 'AR_ADMIN'     |          |
```

My desired result of asking the question 
**What groups is 'USER' a member of?** should be

```
member
==============
'SYSTEM_ADMIN'
'OE_ADMIN'
'AR_ADMIN'
```

## Question

I've got the following query built and providing me with the required results, but it looks a little complex.

```
WITH GM
AS (
    SELECT GROUP_, MEMBER FROM group_members 
       WHERE member IN (SELECT group_ FROM groups)
)
SELECT group_ FROM group_members WHERE member = 'USER'
UNION
SELECT MEMBER AS GROUP_ FROM GM 
   WHERE group_ in (SELECT group_ FROM group_members WHERE member = 'USER')
```

Any suggestions on how to make this query simpler, or less cluttered?

Comment: this is a hierarchical structure, you therefore need a hierarchical query. I don't know sql server but the query you have at the moment seems limited to the first 2 levels in my opinion (omitting that there could be a n-stages group herency)

Comment: Can a group be a member of multiple other groups, or can a group only have one 'parent' group?

Comment: Can you please show sample data *and* desired results?

Comment: @Noah, you raise a good point.  I was originally thinking it would be just two levels.  I'd be interested in seeing an answer that explores the recursive nature of the groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your recursive CTE looks fine.

How does it perform?

I don't think there's any significant way to make it a lot simpler - the recursive CTEs always look kind of messy.

The WHERE IN is equivalent to a JOIN, but I don't see it as being more readable and the execution plan should be pretty equivalent.

Your root row could be represented as a CTE before the recursive one, but it won't really save much in readability:

```
WITH root AS ()
     ,CTE AS ()
SELECT FROM ROOT 
    UNION
SELECT FROM CTE
```

In any case, you could put this in a view or inline table-valued-function (with a parameter) to make it easy to use from elsewhere in the system so you don't have to see it very much.

Something I've done for hierarchies is to build a more high-performance flattened/denormalized version and update it on a trigger or timer and use that as a read-only performance enhancer.  For instance, in a technical support system we build where a question could be tagged in a hierarchy, we filled in all the parents (printers->hp->laserjet) when a child was selected, so it was easy to query for problems with hp printers on any version of Windows or problems with laserjets on Windows XP.

Comment: I was intending to hide this in a view.  Since the expense of calculating the group membership only happens once, per login, I think we can take the performance hit of the hierarchical query.

Comment: @scott-pascoe After looking at your problem again, I'm not sure I understand if your query is working as intended http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/85394/1 Is the SYSTEM_ADMIN a member of both the other groups and the group 'USER'?  Then why shouldn't 'USER' show up in the list?  If group_members indicates the USER is a member of SYTEM_ADMIN, then how does it indicate membership the other way also?

Comment: Actually, upon further reflection, the query does have a problem.  'USER' should not show up in the list, because 'USER' isn't a group, but is a <user>. My table in the question probably obscures the fact that the data is supposed to be three separate tables.

Comment: @scott-pascoe I think the table design isn't clear because group_members looks like it is trying to go both ways and mixing both users and groups.  That is a sign of something not quite right.  There also should be no reason you can't use a recursive CTE to go to arbitrary levels.

Comment: @scott-pascoe If you look at the sqlfiddle in my earlier comment, it does have the three tables as you have them.  I think group_members needs to be redesigned - either split into two tables or have separate columns for group vs users so you can have proper foreign keys.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Cade Roux's answer, further reflection guided me to the following Stored Procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetUserGroups
@user_id varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT group_ FROM group_members WHERE member = @user_id
UNION
SELECT MEMBER AS GROUP_ FROM group_members
WHERE group_ IN (SELECT group_ FROM group_members WHERE member = @user_id) 
      AND member != @user_id
END
```

This simplifies the original query, and properly fulfills my requirement to get back a list of group names that @user_id is a member of, as well as the names of the groups that are members of the top-level group.

This code only allows groups in groups to one level.